# Format csv cells as text with python

Tags: python, text, csv, format

I am giving a row of data to write to a csv file. They are mostly float type numbers. But when it writes to the csv file, the cells are default in custom format. So if I have an input number like 3.25, it prints as "Mar 25". How can I avoid this?
This is the piece of code:

```
data = [0.21, 3.25, 25.9, 5.2]  
f = open('Boot.csv','w')  
out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)  
out.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `csv` module is writing the data fine - I'm guessing that you're opening it in Excel to look at the results and that Excel is deciding to autoformat it as a date.

It's an excel issue, you need to tell it not to play around with that field by changing it to Text (or anything that isn't General)

If you're writing Excel data, you may want to look at the `xlwt` module (check out the very useful site http://www.python-excel.org/) - then your value types will not be so liable to fluctuate.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue, just MS Excel trying to 'help'. If you are going to programmatically process the output csv file further, you'll have no issues.

If you have to process/view the data in Excel you may want to quote all data (by using csv.QUOTE_ALL rather than csv.QUOTE_NONE, in which case Excel should treat everything as text and not try to be 'helpful'.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't part of `csv`. `csv` is nothing more than comma separated values. If you open the file in notepad, it'll be as you expect.

When you open it in excel, it makes a guess as to what each value represents, since this information isn't and can't be encoded in the CSV file. For whatever reason, excel decides `3.25` represents a date, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a format that can't be misinterpreted as a date:

```
out.writerow(['%.12f' % item for item in data])
```

This will include trailing zeros so it should always be parsed by Excel as a number.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the code you've written; it's with Excel (which you're likely using to open the CSV)--it's interpreting `3.25` as `March 25`.  You can fix this by selecting the affected cells, right-clicking and pressing "Format Cells", and then in the "Number" tab selecting "Number" as your category, ensuring that you have the proper number of decimal places displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If all your problem is Excel importing CSV strangely, then you should directly write XLSX files instead of CSV. This gives you full control over the interpretation of cell content.

The best package I have used so far for writing Excel files in Python is [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) (even recommended by the author of the wider spread [xlwt](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt) package).

Some example code taken from the openpyxl docs:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```